# How to render (image) data from the model in the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

That's my controller action

```
public ActionResult ViewImage(int? productId){

           var image = (from x in db.Images
                             where (x.ProductId == productId)
                             select x).ToList();
            return View(image);
       }
```

And that's my view

```
@model
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewImage";
}

<h2>Uploaded pictures</h2>
<div>
<br>
        <img height="300" width="350 " src="@Model" />
</div>
<div>
    <br>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Index","Index","Products")
</div>
```

I don't know what I have to put after @model . I tried to put the type of image but not work!

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the type of model

```
@model List<Images>
```

Comment: The Razor underline Images as a mistake! And I get the error: The type or namespace name 'Images' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Just add the namespace! `@model List<YourAssembly.Images>`

Answer (score 0):

```
Add following property to the model class and add images to it.


public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> AttachImages { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use ViewBag.Image instead of var image:

```
public ActionResult ViewImage(int? productId){
           Viewbag.Image image = (from x in db.Images
                       where (x.ProductId == productId)
                       select x).ToList();
            return View(image);
}
```

Now in your view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewImage";
}

<h2>Uploaded pictures</h2>
<div>
<br>

@foreach(var image in Viewbag.Image)
{
        <img height="300" width="350 " src="@image" />
}
</div>
<div>
    <br>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Index","Index","Products")
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should have a controller action that is streaming the image to the response:

```
public ActionResult Image(int imageId)
{
    var image = db.Images.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == imageId);
    if (image == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    byte[] imageData = image.Data; // or whatever byte[] property you have
    string contentType = "image/jpg"; // or if you have stored the content type in your DB simply assign it to image.ContentType
    return File(imageData, contentType);
}
```

OK, with this handy method in place you could update your view:

```
@model IList<WebApplication1.Image>

<h2>Uploaded pictures</h2>
<div>
    @foreach(var image in Model)
    {
        <img height="300" width="350 " src="@Url.Action("Image", "SomeController", new { imageId = image.Id })" />
    }
</div>
```

Notice how the `src` property of the image is pointing to the controller action we have implemented previously and which will get the image and stream it to the response.